# how to query the result of UNION query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Thank you for your time and apologies if question is silly. I have a result of union query that looks like below. As you can see A and C both have value2 other then NULL. How I can select  B only? I would provide my sql tries but I run out of ideas. I tried count() and sum() and other methods but I always select A B C while I want to get only B.
Thank you.

```
value1 value2 
  A    NULL 
  A    1
  B    NULL
  C    2
  C    3
  C    NULL
```

Thank you so much All for your help. I got the answer and much more! You all are awesome!

Comment: Do you only want B, or do you only want value1 if there is no value2 set?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select value1
from t
group by value1
having count(value2) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are getting stuck on the `UNION` part or the `GROUP BY` so here is my example:

```
SELECT VALUE1 FROM 
(
    --put your UNION query in here, I'm just building your example data
    SELECT 'A' AS VALUE1, NULL AS VALUE2
    UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS VALUE1, 1 AS VALUE2
    UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS VALUE1, NULL AS VALUE2
    UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS VALUE1, 2 AS VALUE2
    UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS VALUE1, 3 AS VALUE2
    UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS VALUE1, NULL AS VALUE2
) AS THETABLE
GROUP BY VALUE1
HAVING COUNT(VALUE2) = 0
```

results:

[image]

There are a bunch of ways to do this, this is just one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with subqueries or CTE's? They allow you to treat result sets like tables.

So...

```
WITH CTE
  ( SELECT * -- Put your union query hear
      FROM YourUnionQuery
  )
-- Then this is the actual transformation you're looking for
    SELECT C1.*  
      FROM CTE C1
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
             ( SELECT 1
                 FROM CTE C2
                WHERE C2.value2 IS NOT NULL
                  AND C2.value1 = C2.value1
             )
```